# Vector $\ [1\ 1\ 1]^T \in R(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that
$\ S=\{ A\in M_3(\mathbb{R}):[1\ 1\ 1]^T \in R(A)\}$ is subspace of $\ M_3\ (\mathbb{R})$

My try:
if vector $\ [1\ 1\ 1]^T\in R(A)$ and $\ [1\ 1\ 1]^T=[0\ 1\ 0]^T+[0\ 0\ 1]^T+[1\ 0\ 0]^T $then this linear combinations belongs to R(A).
Because vectors $\ [0\ 1\ 0]^T,[0\ 0\ 1]^T,[1\ 0\ 0]^T$ then $\ R(A)$ spans the whole space $\ M_3(\mathbb{R})$ therefore $\ S$ is a subspace of$\ M_3(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Your $S$ as it is currently defined is not a subspace.  In particular, it does not contain $0$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would take two elements of $S $, eg $A,B $. Then show that $A+B $ is an element of $S $. Similarly show that for any real number $t $, $tA$ is an element of $S $ whenever $A $ is.
You will not be able to show that $tA $ is in $S$ as pointed in one of the comments.

What you have is wrong, eg take $A=[1 0 0; 1 0 0;1 0 0] $. Even without this issue you have not really shown that $S$ is all of the space of $3×3$ matrices.

Comment: Ask for a hint if you hsve trouble showing what is suggested in the answer or give your attempt.

Comment: Your example isn't in $M_3(\Bbb R)$.  But
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1}
$$
works